# Approval workflow with multiple assignment stages in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, designer-workflow, approval-process, designer

For a while I've been using customised versions of the built-in 2010 SharePoint Designer approval workflows with my SharePoint Online site. I now want to build equivalent workflows using the 2013 platform to take advantage of the more powerful task creation options (I want to assign custom tasks after the approval process has completed).

In a SharePoint 2010 workflow there is an option to add multiple assignment stages, which can independently switched between serial and parallel task assignment:

[image: SharePoint 2010 task properties]

In a SharePoint 2013 workflow there is no such option:

[image: SharePoint 2013 task properties]

Is this just a feature that Microsoft decided to leave out of the 2013 workflow platform, or do I need to look somewhere else to find it?